# Dynamically Create Form Angular2

Tags: forms, angular

I have a table that contains form fields along with data type/length/etc.  What I need to be able to do is generically generate a form from the data in my database.  Then on form submit, serialize the form to JSON.  I am relatively new to Angular2, so any advice on best practice would also be beneficial.

Essentially, something like this where all input's are generated on the fly:

```
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="SaveRow(form)" novalidate>
            <div class="modal-body form-horizontal">

                <div class="form-group row" *ngFor="let column of GetColumns(true)">
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 text-right text-left-xs text-left-sm">
                        <label attr.for="{{column.Name}}" class="control-label">{{column.Name}}<span *ngIf="!column.Nullable">*</span>:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-xs-12">
                        <input id="{{column.Name}}" name="{{column.Name}}" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <div class="text-left">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" *ngIf="IsExisting()" (click)="DeleteRow()">Delete</button>
                    <span class="pull-right text-right">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" id="btnCancel" type="button" (click)="CancelAdd()">Cancel</button>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add Row" *ngIf="!IsExisting()" />
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update Row" *ngIf="IsExisting()" />
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

In my .ts, I have this:

```
SaveRow(form) {
        if (form.valid) {
            var data = new FormData(form);
            console.log("FORM: ");
            console.log(form);
            console.log("DATA: ");
            console.log(data);
        }
    }
```

But I don't believe the input value pairs are showing in the form object that is being submitted.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xYv9lsrV0s4 This might be helpful.

Comment: @bassxzero, video was a great help.  Looks like adding ngModel to each input is what I needed to allow it submit in the form value.